# How can I change strings of "Cancel" button, "No Results" label in UISearchBar of UISearchDisplayController?

Tags: ios, iphone, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

How can I change strings of "Cancel" button, "No Results" label 
in UISearchBar of UISearchDisplayController?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved it myself.

Cancel Button>

```
(void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    [controller.searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:NO];
    for (UIView *subview in [controller.searchBar subviews]) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            [(UIButton *)subview setTitle:@"_____" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

No Results Text>

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (!isChangedNoResults) {
        if ([contactManager.filteredPeople count] == 0) {
            [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(changeNoResultsTextToKorean:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

I use timer and bool value.
If no timer, can not change text when "No Results" show first.

```
- (void)changeNoResultsTextToKorean:(NSTimer *)timer {
    if (isChangedNoResults) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
    else {
        for (UIView *subview in [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView subviews]) {
            if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                UILabel *targetLabel = (UILabel *)subview;
                if ([targetLabel.text isEqualToString:@"No Results"]) {
                    NSLog(@"Changed!");
                    [targetLabel setText:@"_____"];
                    isChangedNoResults = YES;
                    [timer invalidate];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is there anyway to do this without searching the subviews in iOS 5.0 and Arc?

Comment: Maybe this is not needed in iOS5+

Comment: I wrote a relevant article on these kinds of issues: http://artsy.github.com/blog/2012/05/11/on-making-it-personal--in-iOS-with-searchbars/

Comment: Can somebody explain why the timer is needed here? I was curious enough to replace `didLoadSearchResultsTableView:` with `willLoadSearchResultsTableView:` to modify the `No Results` text before it appears, but that doesn't work.

Comment: This code wrote 2 years ago. And now, I develop Android not iOS. So I do not remember exactly... sorry

Answer (score 5):

In order to change the "no result" text you can use :

```
[self.searchDisplayController setValue:@"my no result text"  forKey: @"noResultsMessage"];
```

I've just tested in iOS8

Comment: Tested in iOS7 and iOS8.Works like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you ChangUZ for finding a way. Now, for improvement, a timer is not needed to alter the "No Results" label.

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        for (UIView *v in controller.searchResultsTableView.subviews) {
            if ([v isKindOfClass:[UILabel self]]) {
                ((UILabel *)v).text = @"_____";
                break;
            }
        }
    });
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution for changing the Cancel button text:

```
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setValue:@"custom text" forKey:@"cancelButtonText"];
```

**Tested in iOS 10**