# UISearchBar cancel button change language of word 'cancel' in UISearchDisplayController

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

in iOS5.0 using arc I need to change the word 'cancel' in the cancel button of the UISearchDisplayController to a word derived from the language selected by the user. Since the language is not selected based on localisation, so I cannot just use that. The word comes from a web service. I found a way to do it by walking the subviews in the post below, but is there any other way to do it without assuming apple's view hierarchy?

[How can I change strings of "Cancel" button, "No Results" label in UISearchBar of UISearchDisplayController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238878/how-can-i-change-strings-of-cancel-button-no-results-label-in-uisearchbar-o)

Answer (score 6):

If you want to localize 'cancel' button's title based on different language in iOS System.You can change the `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` key in `Info.plist`.

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en,ru,zh_CN</string>
```

Or you can select them in `Info.plist` file with Xcode Editor.

[image]

Here is the [Language ID](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH15-SW6) from Apple Doc.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you can use the `UIAppearance` protocol to achieve this:

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil]
     setTitle:@"Hello world" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I did only a quick check with the "TableSearch" sample project from Apple, where it worked.

Comment: @Downvoter: It would be nice to leave a comment. I would be glad to know what is wrong with the answer, so that I can fix it.

Comment: Although this works in some cases, worth noting two caveats. As far as I can tell, this is not documented, meaning there is no guarantees from Apple on it continuing to work. Also, although it works in iOS 7.1, it doesn't appear to work in 7.0 (though I haven't tested all patch versions) and I assume it doesn't work in lower iOS versions. If you do go this route, you may want to consider making a `UISearchBar` subclass so that you can have more granular control over which buttons you affect (e.g. `[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABCStyledSearchBar class], nil]`).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] 
                                     setTitle:@"button title" 
                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

if you want to change hint text

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] 
                                        setPlaceholder:@"text hint"];
```

Comment: Is it possible to use similar method on iOS 7?